# Best way to integrate Jquery function in Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

Here again. I would like to understand which one is the best way to integrate a click function inside of angular two, here is the example.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="toggleClass">Item 1</a></li>
    <div class="content hide"></div>
    <li><a href="#" class="toggleClass">Item 2</a></li>
    <div class="content hide"></div>
    <li><a href="#" class="toggleClass">Item 3</a></li>
    <div class="content hide"></div>
    <li><a href="#" class="toggleClass">Item 4</a></li>
    <div class="content hide"></div>
    <li><a href="#" class="toggleClass">Item 5</a></li>
    <div class="content hide"></div>
</ul>
```

And the Jquery function is:

```
$('.toggleClass').click(function() {
         $(this).parent().next('.content').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

What is the best way to integrate inside angular2?

I appreciate your thoughs

Comment: Why would you do that? Angular can handle click events. I'd suggest not to mix jQuery andAngular when it is possible.

Comment: Because I dont know how to find the next .content with Angular2. If you could give me a hand i will be awesome

Comment: @rodboc that's invalid markup div can't/shouldn't be a sibling of list element.

Comment: @Jai should it be the div '.content' inside of each li?